# How To Add Links To Right Of Header?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating this site, just to practice using CSS3 and HTML5 and I've found myself stuck.

I've created a div id for the header and added some CSS to it too but I don't know how to place some links I've created into the header.

I want my nav bar to be on the right hand side of my header kind of like 
[this site](http://helpingdevelop.com/) has done.

I've tried aligning my text to the right of the page using this code: `<P ALIGN=Right>` but all it does is push my links to the right of the page and order them in a list.

Also here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xu3T9/3/) of all the code I have so far.

Comment: just a comments on your code: try not to use capital letters in HTML, aligning does not belong in you html but in your css. check on making navigation menu's using lists : ´<ul>` tag. to align right: use `float: right;` in your css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

navigation is usually created like this: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4csf/)

HTML:

```
 <body>
   <div id = "header">
     <h1>Website</h1>
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Page</a> 
        <li><a href="#">Page</a> 
        <li><a href="#">Page</a>
     </ul> 
   </div>  
 </body>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    text-align: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: -35px;
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

ul li:last-child{
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: You've left out the ending </li>'s

Comment: If that's the case then why not use <header> instead of <div id="header"> ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the links to appear next to each other, then you do not need to wrap them in paragraph tags. This is what is causing the breaks.

Instead of wrapping each link in a paragraph, wrap all of them in a div.

```
<div style="text-align: right;">
    <!--- links --->
</div>
```

This should get the desired affect.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xu3T9/4/)

Comment: even better would be using listings for navigation menu, and avoid inline styles

Answer (score 0):

Threw a div around the links and made it a little more presentable. 
 [View it Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xu3T9/5/)

```
<div id="rightlinks">
    <a href="#">Link 3</a> 
    <a href="#">Link 2</a> 
    <a href="#">Link 1</a> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a quick example. Check it here: http://cdpn.io/txBhd

Important things to keep in mind:

```
- Give h1 a display: inline-block; else you need extra lines of code to do the positioning.
- Apply float to ul, not li, it will reverse the order of your list.
- Use ul and li instead of the p-tag, much easier to control.
- For semantics, use HTML5-tags, such as <header> and <nav>
```